# Detecting Key Press events from saved Systems.Settings variables?

Tags: c#

I am having a hard time detecting Hotkey presses from saved Property.Settings Variables?

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {

        if (keyData == Keys.(Properties.Settings.Default.MasterMonitorHotkey1A) | 
            Keys.(Properties.Settings.Default.MasterMonitorHotkey1B))
        {
            //  Do This & Do That;
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

    }
```

I have tried a few workarounds but just can't get it right...

Comment: Does it get compiled? I cannot see that MasterMonitorHotkey1A is property of Default. Which assembly is required ?

Comment: It creates an error CS1001, "identifier expected" located after the -Keys. in the 1st line of the if statement.  I think I need to figure out how to convert the MasterMonitorHotkey1A into a valid Keys value and then substitute it into the code...